# Oracle SQL Developer и Mysql синтаксис

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

В Oracle SQL Developer пишу следующее:

```
MERGE INTO car_sales_ft t1
USING (SELECT ID, price from actual_price) t2
ON (t1.CarModelid = t2.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.Cost = t2.price;
```

Ошибка такая:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MERGE INTO car_sales_ft t1
>   USING (SELECT ID, price from actual_price) t2 ON (t1.' at line

Получается что MySQL с `MERGE` вообще работать не будет и надо ORACLE XE ставить?

Comment: вам нужно INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE выражение использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Абсолютно верно, mysql не поддерживает `MERGE`.

Я вообще не представляю как можно использовать SQL девелоперер с mysql. У последнего есть своя среда разработки.

Но если вам все таки не хочется переходить на oracle то вам придется сменить среду разработки и изменить синтаксис запроса.

Вы можете использовать [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> Если вы укажете опцию `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` в инструкции `INSERT`, а новая строка вызывает дублирующее значение в индексе `UNIQUE` или `PRIMARY KEY`, MySQL выполняет обновление старой строки на основе новых значений.

Comment: Не совсем понятно - "то вам придется сменить среду разработки". Какое отношение имеет среда разработки к отличиям в обоих, указаных в вопросе, СУБД?

Comment: @0xdb Среда разработки имеет первостепенное значение для разработчика. Вы можете использовать любую среду, но это не будет целесообразно, а также может вызвать множество ошибок. Какую базу данных используете, то используйте соответствующие средства разработки поставляемые вместе с базой данных.

Comment: O целесообразности использования той или иной среды разработки конкретно в этом вопросе речи не идёт, также это не явилось причиной ошибки.